# click event not working on nginclude in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am including a new page using nginclude directive. Click event defined in included page not working.

Main app

```
<div ng-app="">
        <input type="text" ng-model="ss"/>
        <div ng-include src="'include/page1.html'">
        </div>
</div>
```

Page1.html

```
<body>
    <div id="a">{{ss}}</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert("a");
        })
    </script>
</body>
```

why does event defined in page1.html is not working in main app. Is my approach is right or wrong...

Comment: what about `ng-click` in `div id="a"`

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
<div id="a" ng-click="clickHere()">{{ss}}</div>
```

Where clickHere:

```
$scope.clickHere = function(){ alert('a'); };
```